# Facebook Graph API Albums

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need advice, does anyone knows how to order albums by date (chronological, from newer to older ones) with Facebook JavaScript SDK?

I can see 'created_time' field in documentation, is it possible to order albums by this field?

If it is not possible, can you guys at least say how albums originally ordered via API?
Maybe by 'updated_time' field?

Comment: The API doesn’t offer ordering, you’ll have to do that yourself on your end.